# Save POST into a file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, tinymce

I'm using tinymce to edit inline content and then save it via AJAX to a file with PHP.

The problem I'm having is that tinymce fills empty tags, like , so, when I go to PHP, the POST I recieve it's something like this:

```
<td align=\"center\">1,42m<\/td><td align=\"center\">","nbsp;<\/td>
```

I save the content into a file with `file_put_contents`, but the string got cutted, so content file is:

```
<td align="center">1,42m</td><td align="center">
```

and then stop writting.

Does anyone have a clue of how could I fix it?

**Edit**

Problem solved, more or less.

Before initialize tinymce, I find any empty td and then add a zero-space char (HTML `&#8203;`)

Anyway, I left post open for a couple of days, hoping for a better solution.

Comment: This wont fix it, but it should be `&nbsp;` (with a `&` at the front).

Comment: You said.
That doesn't fix the problem. Even I add &nbsp; before tinymce init, but result is the same. I figure I should use some flag or function to save those empty spaces without problem, but I don't know how